# WPF DataGrid Unable To Sort Data From ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding, datagrid

I have a WPF application in which I use entity framework with mysql connector/net to obtain data back. I have a combobox which is filled with items from a table. A datagrids itemssource property is binded to the combobox' selecteditem.staff property, which displays the data correctly. The problem is that I am unable to sort this data. If I bind the data directly to the datagrid, the sorting works correctly. However if I bind the data to the combobox, then bind the datagrid to the selected item of the grid, the sorting is lost.

**Entity Framework Data Retrieval**

```
    private void RefreshOffices()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new LDC_Entities())
            {
                cmbOffice.ItemsSource = context.Offices.Include("Staff.Roles").Include("Manager").ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Unable to retrieve offices\nError:{0}", eX.Message),"Error",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

**XAML Binding**

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbOffice" Width="150" SelectedIndex="0">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
              <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}({0}) - {1}">
                <Binding Path="Office_ID"/>
                <Binding Path="City"/>
              </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,50,10,10" Name="displayGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cmbOffice, Path=SelectedItem.Staff}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Staff ID" Binding="{Binding Staff_ID}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Full_Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="140" Binding="{Binding Address}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DOB" Width="80" Binding="{Binding DOB, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telephone" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Telephone}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Roles" Width="*" Binding="{Binding RolesList}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I have tried playing with the CanUserSort property of the datagrid to no success. I believe it is to do with how the datagrid is filled not by the selected item, but by the .staff collection of staff members.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would try to specify binding direction with [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx) for `DataGrid`, like this

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,50,10,10" Name="displayGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cmbOffice, Path=SelectedItem.Staff, Mode=OneWay}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
```

if this doesn't work for you, another solution could be:

First bind `SelectedItem` of the `combo` to a property, `DataGrid` bind to another collection.
On `combo` binded change, populate `DataGrid`'s binded collection with sorted data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to specify one way but got the same result. I will try your suggestion and make a "CurrentOffice" property which is two way binded by the combobox, then notify the display grid to update see if that works. Thanks